# nodes js MetaMind

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

For a student project, I have to create a chatbot which is able to recognize an image. In order to achieve this recognition I have to use the API MetaMind (https://metamind.io/). This API allows me to predict an image. For instance, if I send a car image, I get the probality that the image is a car.
In the tutorial, I created a DataSet (which contains reference images), then I send a curl request in order to compare my  image to the images of the DataSet. The curl request works well.

The problem I didn't succeed to write this request in javascript file. I tried to user the http module, fs module or request module.
Besides I am a beginner in javascript.

example of the curl request: curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer MyBearer" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "sampleContent=@D:\Projet_IA_Einstein\images\R1.jpg" -F "modelId=MyModelID" https://api.metamind.io/v1/vision/predict

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Olivier

Comment: Can you please provide request package code, that didn't work? They have great docs describing process: https://github.com/request/request#forms

Comment: I think I am on the right track ;)

Nevertheless, I got a other issue about the curl request.
Indeed we realise this request with node js and we got this response: 

Server responded with: {"message":"Credentials are required to access this resource."}

Where do I put the credential in the resquest ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check docs for request's custom headers. You will need to add Authorization header